# display data in specific order in polymer

Tags: javascript, sorting, polymer

In my polymer dom, each data object `todo` has multiple `item`s and it also has a `todo.idx`. I would like to order the `item`s according to its `todo.idx`, instead of their (random) ordering in the data. How can I do it with polymer?

In the [polymer document](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates), it mentions a `sort` function, but I couldn't find examples there. My current code is as follows.

```
    <ol>                                                                     
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{todos}}" as="todo">          
      <li><span> {{todo.item}} </span> </li>             
      </template>                                                            
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort items in polymer using the `sort` attribute, and in your case you would want to use nested templates so you can sort on the `dom-repeat` for a given todo's items:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{todos}}" as="todo">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{todo.items}}" as="item" sort="_sortItems">
    <li><span>{{item}}</span></li>
  </template>
</template>
```

You can then define your `_sortItems` function in same fashion as you would for a compare function in `Array.prototype.sort()`:

```
_sortItems: function(a, b) {
  if (a.idx < b.idx) { return -1; }
  if (a.idx > b.idx) { return 1; }
  return 0;
}
```